# How to rectify this segmentation fault?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

One of my friends is learning pointer concepts so he wrote this program but I don't know why this program is. It is showing a segmentation fault. How can I find the bug in this program?

Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
struct Student
{
    /* data */
    char name[20];
    int age;
    // int rollNo;
};
int main()
{
    struct Student s1;
    struct Student *ptr;
    ptr = &s1;

    scanf("%s",ptr->name);
    scanf("%d",ptr->age);
    // scanf("%d",ptr->rollNo);

    printf("%s",(*ptr).name);
    printf("%d",(*ptr).age);
    // printf("%d",(*ptr).rollNo);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks okay to me.

Comment: Change `scanf("%d",ptr->age);` to `scanf("%d",&ptr->age);`  Your compiler should have warned about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a pointer to *scanf* when you want to read an integer, like this:

```
scanf("%d", &(ptr->age));
```

You also need to make sure that the input is valid by checking the return value, like this:

```
count = scanf("%d", &(ptr->age));
if (count == 1) {
    /*an integer was entered*/
}
```

When you compile a C program you should always enable warnings. For instance the GCC compiler will tell you this about your original program:

```
$ gcc -o test -Wall test.c
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:16:10: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
  scanf("%d", ptr->age);
         ~^   ~~~~~~~~
```